# how to handle '*' in linux bash

Tags: bash

I am having issue with special character `*` in linux . when I do below I am having issue

```
text='*'
```

if I do `echo $text` I am  getting list of all files in the directory.

Please let me know how can I get `*` if I do `echo $text`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the following: `echo "$text"`

Comment: sorry Raj . I should have been more specific in asking my question I am having query like '"select * from ' || table || ' order by id"' my out put will be "select * from name_of_table order by id"

Comment: ... you can also (temporarily if you wish) disable filename generation using the `noglob` shell option (`set -o noglob` or equivalently `set -f`)

Comment: @user1024962 please [edit] your question to show the actual issue that you are trying to solve

Comment: "In linux"? Which linux? Ubuntu? Which  of the programs running on linux?

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this behavior before but this might be a work around
text='*'
echo "${text: -1}"

This escapes the asterisk but the escape char still shows. The second line shows how to get the last character from the string which is the *.

Answer (score 0):

If you escape the character "*" that will work for one print. however you may need to escape the \ as well if your two levels of formatting deep.

"\*"